# How to update (refresh) an Account using a Hyperlink and VFP?

Tags: refresh

On the Account page I am using a Hyperlink "change" to ge to a VFP (Standardcontroller) only.

On the VFP I have two fields to change a number.

With **classic** it works well because I get the number that I entered on the VFP updated on the Account fields.

With **Lightning** the values are not updated when I am redirected to the Account. I have to refresh it once to four times.

How can I avoid that the user has to refresh the page manually?

Comment: Can you post the minimal required code from your vf page by editing your question?

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this issue because of some cache issue with lightning experience. This is an intermittent behavior and could happen when we are performing the updates continuously and redirecting to the page, within a span of 30 secs. If the same transaction is repeated after 30 secs or more no issues observed. This is a known issue, reported here https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001C8QQAU&title=data-not-updated-in-ui-after-an-apex-update-in-lightning-experience. Please check the workaround section to resolve the issue until salesforce fixes it.

Comment: Thank you. So that is normal for lightning?!

Comment: Yes for now. May be in future sales force will resolve this issue.